# ngActiveResource all() with nested REST response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am using [ngActiveResource](https://github.com/FacultyCreative/ngActiveResource) for my models and interacting with my REST API.  (I'm really impressed with it)

It is working well with single models as the server response (show) is "flat" eg:

```
{
    "pk": 42692
}
```

However with 'index'/list responses the data is nested eg:

```
{
    "num_results": 1, 
    "objects": [
        {
            "pk": 42692
        }
    ], 
    "page": 1, 
    "total_pages": 1
}
```

This results in ngActiveResource creating 4 models all of which are empty.  I assume this is one for each attribute ("num_results", "objects", "page", "total_pages") and all empty as the data they contain does not line up with the model definition.

How do I go about telling ngActiveResource that the data is nested?  Is there a way to intercept the request?  I know it is built upon angular's $resource so it must be possible.